# using jaspersoft ireport 5.6.0 to generate pdf in php. Issue in arabic language on pdf

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

Using Jaspersoft ireport 5.6.0 to generate pdf in php. I already used Arial.ttf for Arabic language in Jaspersoft. In Jaspersoft pdf preview is working fine but when I viewed in my application it wont show the correct format. I dont know where should I change.

Arabic language error in pdf
[image: Arabic language error in pdf]

Jaspersoft internal preview
[image: Jaspersoft internal preview]

jaspersoft font select
[image: jaspersoft font select]

Answer (score 2):

JasperReports uses an old(er) version of `iText` to generate its PDF documents.
There are many (mostly legal) reasons why they have chosen to stay with this older version.

This sadly implies that their customers are stuck using technology that is almost a decade old. And because this is used by JasperReports internally, it can be hard to debug these issues.

The latest release of `iText`, in combination with `pdfCalligraph` should enable you to write Arabic, Hindi, Tamil, and many other non-western languages perfectly.

Because of these known issues, iText has come up with a solution of its own for templating, which they presented at GIDS (http://developermarch.com/developersummit/session.html?insert=Chanpreet)